# Authentication using OAuth in Web API

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I'm working on a project using ASP.Net MVC5 which also includes a Web API. The API will be for internal use only. I'm using the OWIN library to provider authentication.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to correctly implement authentication through the API. I was planning on using OAuth 2.0 but the problem with OAuth is that the user needs to login through a browser page instead of a native login screen. So I was wondering if it is possible to somehow skip the browser.

I've found [this](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#tests/Katana.Sandbox.WebServer/Startup.cs) example which creates it's own OAuth Authorization Server. But it doesn't show how to make the login native.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a highly trusted client, then you can use the OAuth2 resource owner password flow. You can look at the VS2013 SPA template and/or read on this post:

http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/13/embedding-a-simple-usernamepassword-authorization-server-in-web-api-v2/

Answer (score 4):

You could use Thinktecture.IdentityServer v2 as a light-weight security token service.

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2

Answer (score -2):

You will need to create a `WOPI` host, which is basically a software solution that can take advantage of the `browser-based Office`(`office web`).

Create a custom `WOPI` host and configure it to use Office Web Apps Server to provide the browser-based file viewing and editing for Office files.

Nice sample on [Microsoft MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6)